# BASH extract column name from the highest column sum txt file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a .txt file containing the following:

```
reference a b c

SR48 250 1250 1256

SR49 310 1651 1684
```

I would like to find the shortest way to get the column name of the column that gets the highest value when summing all the column values. In this case, it would be c.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please do add your efforts in form of code, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)fields[i]=$i; cnt=NF; next}
     {for(i=2;i<=cnt;i++) sums[fields[i]]+=$i}
     END{for (e in sums) if (sums[e]>max){max=sums[e]; idx=e}
     print idx, max}
' file
```

Prints:

```
c 2940
```